# TRANSLATION Change the content default language

Tags: translation

i create my website with French as a default language(Dashboard and website content) and when i finished i install a Translation Plugin 'TranslatePress' to translate my website to English, and as you know "www.mywebsite.com/" is the default and has the Fr version and "www.mywebsite.com/en" for the English version.

My question is how to make the English version translation(website content) is the default one instead of French withou losing any existing translation ?

Thank you in Advance